# Níveis em jogo da velha

Tags: python

Estou trabalhando em um jogo da velha em Python, e tenho códigos de 3 níveis (fácil, médio e difícil) distintos, como poderia implementar um "menu" inicial onde o usuário pudesse escolher um dos níveis e ser imediatamente direcionado para o mesmo. E ao fim do jogo ele pudesse escolher o nível novamente.

```
import random

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Funções utilizadas pelo programa 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# função que atualiza a estrutura de dados que representa as filas de fechamento
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def atualizaFilas():
    global lins, cols, dgns

    lins = [linha for linha in tabuleiro]

    cols = [
            [tabuleiro[linha][0] for linha in range(3)], \
            [tabuleiro[linha][1] for linha in range(3)], \
            [tabuleiro[linha][2] for linha in range(3)]  \
           ]

    dgns = [
            [tabuleiro[linha][linha]  for linha in range(3)],
            [tabuleiro[linha][coluna] for linha in range(3)
                                          for coluna in range(3)
                                              if (linha+coluna) == 2]
           ]

    return(lins + cols + dgns)

# função que apresenta jogo ao usuário
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def apresentaJogo():
    print(2*'\n')
    print('Nesta implementação do Jogo da Velha, as casas do tabuleiro são numeradas da seguinte forma: \n\n' \
          ' 11 | 12 | 13 \n' \
          '----+----+----\n' \
          ' 21 | 22 | 23 \n' \
          '----+----+----\n' \
          ' 31 | 32 | 33 \n')
    print('Ao fazer seu lance, indique em qual dessas casas você quer jogar.')

# função que exibe o tabuleiro
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def exibeTabuleiro():
    print()
    print(' ' + tabuleiro[0][0] + ' |' + ' ' + tabuleiro[0][1] + ' |' + ' ' + tabuleiro[0][2] + ' \n' \
          '---+---+---\n' \
          ' ' + tabuleiro[1][0] + ' |' + ' ' + tabuleiro[1][1] + ' |' + ' ' + tabuleiro[1][2] + ' \n' \
          '---+---+---\n' \
          ' ' + tabuleiro[2][0] + ' |' + ' ' + tabuleiro[2][1] + ' |' + ' ' + tabuleiro[2][2] + ' \n' )

# função que verifica o fechamento do jogo
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def verificaFechamento():

    # seta indicador de fechamento
    for fila in filas:
        if fila in fechamentos:
            status = True
            break
    else:
        status = False

    return status

# função que obtém e processa lance do jogador
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def processaLanceJogador():
    global filas, jogada, tabuleiro

    # contabiliza jogada do jogador
    jogada += 1

    # exibe lista de casas disponíveis
    print('\nNo momento, o tabuleiro está com as seguintes casas disponíveis:\n', \
          casasDisponíveis, '\n')

    # obtém lance do jogador
    while True:
        try:
            casa = int(input('Em qual delas você quer jogar? '))
            if casa not in casasDisponíveis:
                raise ValueError
            else:
                # elimina casa escolhida da relação das casas disponíveis
                casasDisponíveis.remove(casa)
                break
        except ValueError:
            print('Você digitou um valor inválido ou uma casa já ocupada. Tente novamente.\n')

    # atualiza tabuleiro
    tabuleiro[casa//10-1][casa%10-1] = 'X'

    # atualiza a estrutura de dados que representa as filas de fechamento
    filas = atualizaFilas()

# função que obtém lance do computador
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def processaLanceComputador():
    global jogada, filas

    # contabiliza jogada do computador
    jogada += 1
    # gera lance do computador
    casa = random.choice(casasDisponíveis)
    # elimina casa escolhida da relação das casas disponíveis
    casasDisponíveis.remove(casa)
    # atualiza tabuleiro
    tabuleiro[casa//10-1][casa%10-1] = 'O'
    # atualiza a estrutura de dados que representa as filas de fechamento
    filas = atualizaFilas()

# inicializa a estrutura de dados que representa o tabuleiro
tabuleiro = [[' ']*3, [' ']*3, [' ']*3]

# define e inicializa a estrutura de dados que representa os padrões de fechamento
fechamentos = [3*['X'], 3*['O']]

# cria lista de casas disponíveis para lance
casasDisponíveis = [i*10+j for i in range(1,4) \
                               for j in range(1,4) \
                                   if tabuleiro[i-1][j-1] == ' ']

# inicializa a estrutura de dados que representa as filas de fechamento
filas = atualizaFilas()

# seta a condição de encerramento do jogo
jogada, fechou = 0, False
terminar = (jogada == 9) or (fechou == True)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Corpo do programa
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# apresenta jogo ao jogador
apresentaJogo()

# enquanto não terminar
while (not terminar):
    # processa jogada do jogador
    processaLanceJogador()
    # verifica Fechamento
    fechou = verificaFechamento()
    # atualiza sinalizador de encerramento do jogo
    terminar = (jogada == 9) or fechou == True
    # se for para terminar:
    if terminar:
        # exibe tabuleiro
        exibeTabuleiro()
        # termina o jogo
        break
    # processa jogada do computador
    processaLanceComputador()
    # verifica Fechamento
    fechou = verificaFechamento()
    # atualiza sinalizador de encerramento do jogo
    terminar = (jogada == 9) or fechou == True
    # exibe tabuleiro
    exibeTabuleiro()

# em caso de fechamento, verifica vencedor e emite mensagem correspondente:
if fechou:
   # se o vencedor for o jogador:
    if jogada in [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]:
       # emite mensagem de congratulação:
        print('Parabéns, você venceu!')
   # se o vencedor for o computador:
    else:
       # emite mensagem de zoação:
        print('Você é um pato!')
# se a partida não fechou, emite mensagem de empate
else:
    print('Deu velha !')
```

Comment: Se sua questão é apenas implementar um menu, sugiro usar algum GUI como PyQt, Kivy, Tkinter, etc.

Comment: Mas eu não quero uma interface gráfica, queria apenas que ao abrir o programa o usuário pudesse escolher o nível e ser direcionado para o mesmo.  O ideal seria o usuário digitar "fácil" e ser direcionado para esse nível. Não sei se seria possivel isso com o tkinter

Comment: Esse código que eu postei é do nível fácil, existem mais 2, "juntar" os três e aplicar esse menu inicial

Comment: Se não quer interface gráfica, use então `input`. Ex: https://www.python-course.eu/input.php

Comment: Fico imaginando como é que funcionaria nível no jogo da velha. Tecnicamente nem é um jogo, pois duas pessoas que sabem jogar empatarão eternamente. Só se o algoritmo sortear primeiro se vai perder ou não, em porcentagens diferentes.

Comment: @Bacco, eu criei há algum tempo um jogo da velha em Java, onde o jogador joga contra o computador. Daí dá para definir os níveis de "esperteza" do computador...

Comment: @RogérioDec, muito obrigado, mas como eu faço para interligar os 3 níveis no mesmo código?

Comment: Dá para fazer isso que você deseja usando "agentes inteligentes". Não se preocupe, é IA mas não é nada do outro mundo. É só uma modelagem, que no caso é adequada para o seu caso. Um dos agentes pode ser o jogador, e o outro agente a máquina que desafiará o jogador.

Answer (score 1):

Para repetir varias vezes e poder escolher a dificuldade:

```
jogando = True
while jogando:
    #Você pode criar uma função que dê print o menu e retorne a dificuldade ou sair
    print("Dificuldades:")
    print("1 - Fácil")
    print("2 - Médio")
    print("3 - Difícil")
    print("\n4 - Sair")
    dificuldade = input("Digite a dificuldade desejada ou saia(Ex.: 1 OU `facil`): ")
    while dificuldade != '1' and dificuldade != '2' and dificuldade != '3' and dificuldade.lower() != 'facil' and dificuldade.lower() != 'medio' and dificuldade.lower() != 'dificil' and dificuldade != '4' and dificuldade.lower() != 'sair':
        dificuldade = input("\nEscolha Inválida!\nDigite a dificuldade desejada (Ex.: 1 OU `facil`): ")
    if dificuldade == '4' or dificuldade.lower() == 'sair':
        terminar = True
        jogando = False
    else:
        apresentaJogo()
    # enquanto não terminar
    while (not terminar):
       # processa jogada do jogador
       processaLanceJogador()
       # verifica Fechamento
       fechou = verificaFechamento()
       # atualiza sinalizador de encerramento do jogo
       terminar = (jogada == 9) or fechou == True
       # se for para terminar:
       if terminar:
          # exibe tabuleiro
          exibeTabuleiro()
          # termina o jogo
          break
      # processa jogada do computador
      if dificuldade == '1' or dificuldade.lower() == 'facil':
          processaLanceComputador(1) #OU processaLanceFacilComputador()
      elif dificuldade == '2' or dificuldade.lower() == 'medio':
          processaLanceComputador(2) #OU processaLanceMedioComputador()
      elif dificuldade == '3' or dificuldade.lower() == 'dificil':
          processaLanceComputador(3) #OU processaLanceDificilComputador()
      # verifica Fechamento
      fechou = verificaFechamento()
      # atualiza sinalizador de encerramento do jogo
      terminar = (jogada == 9) or fechou == True
      # exibe tabuleiro
      exibeTabuleiro()

      # em caso de fechamento, verifica vencedor e emite mensagem correspondente:
      if fechou:
      # se o vencedor for o jogador:
         if jogada in [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]:
             # emite mensagem de congratulação:
             print('Parabéns, você venceu!')
         # se o vencedor for o computador:
         else:
             # emite mensagem de zoação:
             print('Você é um pato!')
             # se a partida não fechou, emite mensagem de empate
      else:
         print('Deu velha !')
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem o código que fiz (jogador contra computador). Não é IA, mas o computador pode jogar em nível "iniciante" (para crianças) e "experto" (onde ele não falha). 
Na época fiz para aprender **Java**, então está nesta linguagem, mas é facilmente adaptável para Python.

O código abaixo é apenas o kernel em Java (não inclui a interface gráfica), mas tem toda a lógica para você converter para Python ou qualquer outra linguagem:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
//import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

/**
 * Created by Rogério Dec (http://rogeriodec.com.br - rogeriodec@gmail.com) on 20/01/2017.
 */
public class Velha {
    public static int i, ContMatriz, jogada, jogadaX, numjogada = 0;
    public static char[] MatrizJogo = new char[10];
    public static int[][] JogadasPossiveis = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9}, {1, 5, 9}, {3, 5, 7}};
    public static int[][] Log = new int[2][10];
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    public static String Velha(int botao) {
        if (JogoDaVelha.Iniciante.isSelected()) { // modo iniciante
            if (botao == 0) // computador começa
                PreencheVazio('O');
            else {
                MatrizJogo[botao] = 'X'; // armazena jogada humana na matriz, posição escolhida
                ContMatriz++;
                if (FazVelha('X') == 3)  // Jogador X fez 3 casas (velha)?
                    return "X"; // humano ganhou
                PreencheVazio('O');
                if (FazVelha('O') == 3) 
                    return "O"; // máquina ganhou
                if (ContMatriz > 8) // não achou jogada possível, preenche qualquer um ...
                    return "E"; // empate
            }
        }
        else { // modo experto
            if (botao == 0) // computador começa
                ataca();
            else {
                MatrizJogo[botao] = 'X'; // armazena jogada humana na matriz, posição escolhida
                ContMatriz++; // incrementa contador da matrizes já utilizadas
                // fechou velha?
                if (FazVelha('X') == 3)  // Jogador X fez 3 casas (velha)?
                    return "X"; // humano ganhou
                jogadaX = jogada; // guarda para comparar jogadaX
                if (FazVelha('O') == 2) {
                    jogadaX = jogada; // guarda para comparar jogadaX
                    defende();
                    return "O";
                }
                // humano consegue velha?
                if (FazVelha('X') == 2)  // Jogador X fez 2 casas, então pode fazer velha
                    defende();
                else 
                    ataca();
                if (ContMatriz >= 8) // não achou jogada possível, preenche qualquer um ...
                    return "E"; // empate
                // máquina consegue velha?
            }
        }

//        ********** começa computador, modo experto, x = 3, 4, O = 5, 1 e ai faz 8 e 9 de uma vez
        return null;
    }

     public static void desenha(){
        if (MatrizJogo[1] != '\0') JogoDaVelha.b1.setText((Character.toString(MatrizJogo[1])));
        if (MatrizJogo[2] != '\0') JogoDaVelha.b2.setText((Character.toString(MatrizJogo[2])));
        if (MatrizJogo[3] != '\0') JogoDaVelha.b3.setText((Character.toString(MatrizJogo[3])));
        if (MatrizJogo[4] != '\0') JogoDaVelha.b4.setText((Character.toString(MatrizJogo[4])));
        if (MatrizJogo[5] != '\0') JogoDaVelha.b5.setText((Character.toString(MatrizJogo[5])));
        if (MatrizJogo[6] != '\0') JogoDaVelha.b6.setText((Character.toString(MatrizJogo[6])));
        if (MatrizJogo[7] != '\0') JogoDaVelha.b7.setText((Character.toString(MatrizJogo[7])));
        if (MatrizJogo[8] != '\0') JogoDaVelha.b8.setText((Character.toString(MatrizJogo[8])));
        if (MatrizJogo[9] != '\0') JogoDaVelha.b9.setText((Character.toString(MatrizJogo[9])));
        numjogada++;
        int jogador = 0;
        for (int casa = 1; casa < 10; casa++) {
acha:       {
                if (MatrizJogo[casa] == '\0')
                    continue;
                if (MatrizJogo[casa] == 'X')
                    jogador = 0;
                if (MatrizJogo[casa] == 'O')
                    jogador = 1;
                for (i = 1; i<10; i++) { // ve se a casa já havia sido registrada em aguma jogada
                    if (Log[jogador][i] == casa)
                        break acha; // se já havia sido registrada, vai para proxima casa
            }
            Log[jogador][numjogada] = casa;
            }
        }
    }

    private static int FazVelha (char jogador) {
        int ContVelha, ContVelhaAnt = 0, jogadaAnt = 0;
        for (jogada=0; jogada<8; jogada++) { // Rastreia Jogadas Possíveis, uma por uma para ver qual tem mais combinações
            ContVelha = 0;
            for (int casa = 0; casa < 3; casa++) { // compara
                int CasaPossivel = JogadasPossiveis[jogada][casa];
                if (MatrizJogo[CasaPossivel] == jogador)
                    ContVelha++;
                else if (MatrizJogo[CasaPossivel] != '\0'){ // se casa estiver preenchida com do OUTRO jogador, anula esta jogada possível
                    ContVelha = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
//            if (ContVelha >= 3)
            if (ContVelha >= (JogoDaVelha.Iniciante.isSelected() ? 3 : 2)) {
                if (ContVelhaAnt < ContVelha) {
                    ContVelhaAnt = ContVelha;
                    jogadaAnt = jogada;
                }
            }
        }
        jogada = jogadaAnt;
        return ContVelhaAnt;
    }

    private static void defende() {
        int ContVazias = 0, casa, ContImpares = 0;
        for (casa = 0; casa < 3; casa++) {
            if (MatrizJogo[JogadasPossiveis[jogadaX][casa]] == '\0') // encontrou casa vazia
                ContVazias++;
        }
        if (ContVazias == 0) {
            PreencheVazio('O');
            return;
        }
        if (ContVazias == 3) { // se as 3 casas da jogada escolhida estiverem vazias, joga numa que não seja par
            int [] CasasImpares = new int [3];
            for (casa = 0; casa < 3; casa++) { // conta quantas casas da jogada são impares
                if (JogadasPossiveis[jogadaX][casa] % 2 != 0) 
                    CasasImpares[ContImpares++] = JogadasPossiveis[jogadaX][casa];
            }
            if (ContImpares == 1) // se encontrou apenas 1 casa impar na jogada escolhida
                casa = CasasImpares[0]; // pega a 1a casa impar encontrada
            else 
                casa = CasasImpares[rnd.nextInt(ContImpares)]; // sorteia entre a 1a e a 2a casa impar encontrada
            MatrizJogo[casa] = 'O';
        }
        else {
            int CasaEscolhida = rnd.nextInt(ContVazias);
            i = 0;
            for (casa = 0; casa < 3; casa++) {
                if (MatrizJogo[JogadasPossiveis[jogadaX][casa]] == '\0') {
                    if (i == CasaEscolhida) {
                        MatrizJogo[JogadasPossiveis[jogadaX][casa]] = 'O'; // preenche com O
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        ContMatriz++;
    }

    private static void ataca() {
        if (ContMatriz == 0) { // primeira jogada, computador começando
            int [] primeiraJogada = {1,3,5,7,9};
            i = rnd.nextInt(5); 
            MatrizJogo[primeiraJogada[i]] = 'O';
            ContMatriz++;
            return;
        }

        i=0;
        int [] JogadasPossiveisO = new int [8];
        int [] ProbabilidadeJogada = new int [8];
        int ContProb=0; // contador de probabilides encontradas

        // Rastreia Jogadas Possíveis para O (máquina)
        for (jogada = 0; jogada < 8; jogada++) {
            proxJogada: {
                for (int casa = 0; casa < 3; casa++) { // compara
                    int CasaPossivel = JogadasPossiveis[jogada][casa];
                    if (MatrizJogo[CasaPossivel] == 'X') { // se encontrou algum X, a jogada não é possível, tenta outra jogada possível
                        if (ProbabilidadeJogada[i] > 0) {
                            ProbabilidadeJogada[i] = 0; // zera contador de probabilidade desta jogada
                            ContProb--; // volta no contador de probabilidades
                        }
                        break proxJogada;
                    }
                    if (MatrizJogo[CasaPossivel] == 'O') { // se encontrou algum O, aumenta a probabilidade da jogada se escolhida
                        ProbabilidadeJogada[i]++; // aumenta contador de probabilidade desta jogada
                        ContProb++; // mais uma probabilidade encontrada
                    }
                }
                JogadasPossiveisO[i++] = jogada;
            }
        } // aqui já tem todas as jogadas possívels para O suas probabilidades
        if (i == 0) { // se não encontrou nenhuma jogada possível, preenche qualquer espaço vazio para acabar o jogo
            PreencheVazio('O');
            return;
        }
        int MelhorJogada = 0;
        int JogadaEscolhida = 0;
        int x = 0;
        if (ContProb == 0) 
            MelhorJogada = rnd.nextInt(i); 
        else {
            JogadaEscolhida = rnd.nextInt(ContProb); // define aleatoriamente qual das melhores jogadas encontradas será usada
            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) { // localiza a jogada de maior probabilidade
                if (ProbabilidadeJogada[i] > 0) {
                    if (x == JogadaEscolhida) {
                        MelhorJogada = i; // define qual a melhor jogada
                        break;
                    }
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }
        jogadaX = JogadasPossiveisO[MelhorJogada]; // define a melhor jogada dentro da maior probabilidade. Se nenhuma probabilidade foi encontrada, pega a 1a jogada possível.
        defende(); // preenche a jogada
    }
    private static void PreencheVazio(char jogador) {
        int [] vazios = new int[10];
        int ContVazios = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) { // procura primeiro espaço vazio
            if (MatrizJogo[i] == '\0') 
                vazios[++ContVazios] = i;
        }
        if (ContVazios != 0) {
            i = rnd.nextInt(ContVazios) + 1; 
            MatrizJogo[vazios[i]] = jogador;
        }
        ContMatriz++;
    }
}
```